# How to debug a hanging sort -u job?

Tags: sort

I have a 32GB text file I am trying to remove duplicate lines and sort using `sort -u mybigfile.txt`. The job hangs forever so I ended up splitting it into 10 files and one of those 10 files wont finish the `sort -u` job.

How do I troubleshoot which line in my file is causing my hangup? I am trying to avoid just splitting this file 1000 times until I find the line :)

If it matters at all, i am doing this on WSL. thanks so much

Comment: Even if you keep splitting it in two pieces instead of ten, it will take you about 20 steps, not 1000 until you narrow it down to a 32kbytes file.

Comment: How do you know the job _hangs_ (i.e., that it is making no forward progress) vs it simply taking a long time to complete?

Comment: Andy Dalton - first of all, RIP to you and the Cowboys ;). I split my source file into 10 files with equal line counts, each file is around 2GB. I can run sort -u on all the other files and it completes in 5-10 minutes. The hanging files never complete, i have left them to run overnight with what appears to be 0 progress. Thanks.

Comment: Is it using CPU (check in `top`)? Can you `export LC_ALL=C` and try that 2GB file (i.e. avoid UTF-8 issues)? Will it complete a plain sort (you can always use `uniq` on it separately)?

Comment: Does sort (without -u) on that file complete its job?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant - CPU is low the whole time. Mark Plotnick - it appears that sort without -u does not ever complete

Comment: @Paul_Pedant setting that export seems to have done the trick! if you want to post an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it merits being an answer: my three suggestions were all responses to your "How to debug..". Changing the sort locale may affect other readers of the file (join, diff, comm etc) which may use a different locale and therefore recognise different order. In particular, it would be good to know if this (apparent) bug is related to the actual sort, or to the specific `-u` option.

Comment: As it happens, I *never* use `sort -u`: on some systems (e.g. Solaris) it does not do what `sort | uniq` does, if you specify partial keys. `sort -u` discards rows where the *keys* are identical (even where other fields differ): `sort | uniq` discards rows where the *rows* are identical. (I never checked GNU for this behaviour.)